Get charts from sheet and send to email
I have the following code below.
const SHEET_NAMES = ["BaseGraficos"];
function main(wb: ExcelScript.Workbook): string {
    const sheets = SHEET_NAMES.map((name) => wb.getWorksheet(name));
    const htmlBody = createHtmlBody(sheets);
    return htmlBody;
}
function createHtmlBody(sheets: ExcelScript.Worksheet[]) {
    let html = `<table>`;
    sheets.forEach((sheet) => {
        const charts = getChartFromSheet(sheet);
        charts.forEach((chart) => {
            html += `<tr><td><h3>${sheet.getName()}</h3></td></tr>`;
            html += `<tr><td><img src="${chart}"></td></tr>`;
        });
    });
    html += `</table>`;
    return html;
}
function getChartFromSheet(sheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet) {
    const charts = sheet.getCharts();
    return charts.map((chart) => {
        return `data:image/png;base64,${chart.getImage()}`;
    });
}

It will provide me with an HTML table with the charts from my BaseCharts spreadsheet.
In Power Automate, I have a flow that will take this HTML table and assemble the body of the email.
However, when putting together the email, it is noticed that the axes of most of the charts get messed up>
Here is one that i got mailed:
enter image description here
And here is the one thats in my sheet:
enter image description here
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong??
Here is the Excel file without sensitive
data:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/11bHBcC3umDH7DZyiD9RFyXZSrbf-03ZZ/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel
Here is the flow (triggered by recurrence):
flow
Here is the error from my Copy and Paste Script:
ERROR

Hi @parizi10 - I tried the script you shared and it seemed to work fine for me, so I wonder if the issue is due to the way some of your charts are configured. Which charts are getting rendered correctly, and which aren't? Alternatively, would you be able to share a sample workbook (sensitive data removed as needed) so we can try to reproduce the issue?

Yes i sure can! The charts that are getting messed up are the ones with DATE x axis. The ones there are with plain text as X axis seems to work fine.
But for some unknown reason, even when I transform the DATE in TEXT, using TEXT('date cells',"dd/mm") and changing the cells to text, the CHART when email keep up with the same error...
Anyways, i'm editting my question and including the excel sheet.

@MichelleRan ive just added the file sample!

It looks like the file is no longer available - would you be able to reupload it?

Thanks! I was able to test with the file and noticed that the charts in the yellow section appeared different when I downloaded the file vs. the preview in Google Drive. However, when I ran your script to email the chart images, all the yellow charts rendered exactly as they did in my copy of the file. I did notice your workbook contained Power BI connections; are those used for the yellow charts?

@MichelleRan yes they do use data that comes from a power bi data set! As it is the Only refreshable option that can run by a power automate script trigger.

Thanks for clarifying - I'm currently testing to see if I can reproduce this issue. To confirm, is there any additional code in your script or prior step in your flow that modifies the workbook or the Power BI dataset?

@MichelleRan nope, the flow is triggered by recurrence. it only runs the script and then put it in the outlook body.
I've just uploaded  a screenshot of the flow. thank you!!!

Apologies for the delay here - I'm still investigating internally. If it's not trouble, I had two additional questions: 1. Does your script produce the correct result when you run it in Excel rather than Power Automate? 2. It seems like some formulas or other configuration is getting lost when I download your file. Could you please confirm whether the uploaded file is correct?

@MichelleRan
I belive that it does. I think i should modify the script só it generate the charts in a new sheet. About the formulas… All o did was copy and then paste values Only, because the fórmulas would be related to sheets that have sensitive data. The formulas where some COUNT.Ifs

Hi @parizi10, thanks for your patience - while I've not yet reproduced the issue, one possibility is that the Power BI data has not yet been loaded in by the time the script pulls the chart image. Could you try making your script wait for a few seconds before getting the images? Here's an example: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/tbmzav/comment/k8w2h3q/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

@MichelleRan i've notice that the error only appears when the values come as a result of a formula.
I've also made a script that copy the range and then paste them into another cell. surprisingly, it works with an error, even when i set 100s of delay following your tutorial... ive printed the error and just put it on my post!

Oh, that's quite strange... Could you share the script you used to copy-paste the values?

@MichelleRan Yes iwill sent it on monday.
When i run manually the script on the sheet it works. But When it is run by the power automate trigger runs but buged. Craaazy

@MichelleRan
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("BaseGraficos");

let targetRange1 = selectedSheet.getRange("AD1")

let sourceRange1 = selectedSheet.getRange("E1:X32")

targetRange1.copyFrom(sourceRange1,ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values)

}

This looks like a straightforward script and worked fine for me, so between the copy-pasting failing and the charts rendering incorrectly, I'm inclined to think Power Automate may be interacting strangely with your specific formulas. Unfortunately, I think we're reaching the limits of how far we can troubleshoot without access to the original file - I'd recommend you reach out to support. I'm very sorry I can't help more!

@MichelleRan sure, is clear now that the interation between Power Automate and the data that comes from the PBI service is getting messed up... any clue on how i reach out microsoft about this problem?
Thanks for your support!!!

I'd recommend starting from the official support website or checking if your organization has any dedicated support channels. Hopefully that helps!
